# Return result sets from stored procedure in Postgres v12

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-12

How to return result sets from a procedure in Postgres v12(beta).

The link below says that changes have been done in Postgres v12 beta.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TODO#Server-Side_Languages:

> ### Server-Side Languages
>
> ---
>
> □ Add support for polymorphic arguments and return types to languages other than PL/PgSQL
>
> □ Add support for OUT and INOUT parameters to languages other than PL/PgSQL
>
> □ Add more fine-grained specification of functions taking arbitrary data types
>
> ▪  [RfD: more powerful "any" types](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2009-09/msg00367.php)
>
> [D] ✓ Implement stored procedures
>
> This might involve the control of transaction state and the return of multiple result sets
>
> ▪ [PL/pgSQL stored procedure returning multiple result sets (SELECTs)?](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2008-10/msg00454.php)
>      ▪ [Proposal: real procedures again (8.4)](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2007-10/msg01375.php)
>      ▪ http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2010-09/msg00542.php
>      ▪ [Gathering specs and discussion on feature (post 9.1)](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2011-04/msg01149.php)

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are referring to “returning multiple result sets”.

First, the page you are showing is from the PostgreSQL TODO list, which is not a list of new features in v12, but a collection of things that might be useful to implement — a wish list rather than a feature list.

Stored procedures have been introduced in v11, but there is no support for multiple result sets yet.

Comment: Of course; silly mistake.